# Makefile refuses to match target patterns under strange circumstances

Tags: makefile

I encountered some strange behavior, when one runs

```
make hello-there
```

and the makefile is

```
hello-%:
    @echo hi $*
```

I get

```
hi there
```

But when the makefile is just

```
hello-%:
```

I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `hello-there'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Doesn't the error just mean that there are no rules under the `hello-%:` heading?

Comment: Indeed, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case you are not definign any rule for `hello-%`.

From chapter 5 of the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipe-Syntax.html#Recipe-Syntax):

> Each line in the recipe must start with a tab, except that the first
>   recipe line may be attached to the target-and-prerequisites line with
>   a semicolon in between

You have to ways of solving this:

- Add a semicolon at the end of the line defining the target name:

  hello-%: ;
- Add a line containing only a tab below the the one defining the target name